# MVC application with azure authentication

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, owin, openid-connect

Am creating an application with azure authentication(MVC5).Everything working in local when running in IIS Express. When am hosting the application to local IIS, application is redirecting to Microsoft login page for user authentication and after entering the credentials its not coming back to the redirect URL which I mentioned in the Azure application.

When the examine the URL, **a new nonce cookies is keep on generating** and appending to the URL and atlast getting **BAD REQUEST ERROR**

Startup.Auth.cs code

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
                });
        }
    }
```

I got some sample project from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/) and its working fine after hosting also.

If anyone facing this issue???????????

Answer (score 0):

Did you try modifying the MaxFieldLength and the MaxRequestBytes registry settings on the IIS server so the user's request headers are not considered too long?

Comment: Yes. But no change